# bash on windows で anaconda3 をインストールして import matplotlib.pyplot するとエラーになる

Tags: python, windows-10, matplotlib, anaconda, wsl

【症状】
bash on windows で anaconda3 をインストールして matplotlib のデモファイル [dete_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html) を走らせるとエラーが出ます。

【行った手順】
● lxrun /uninstall , lxrun /install
● bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
● python -V  # Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)
● python date_demo.py      ## 別記エラー１

【行った対応】
No module named 'PyQt4' とあったので PyQt4 をインストールしなくてはならないのか？？
● conda list | grep pyqt   ## pyqt 5.6.0 py35_0
● conda list | grep PyQt4  ## なし
● conda search PyQt4       ## なし
● pip search PyQt4         ## PyQt4 (4.11.4) がlist内にあった
● pip install PyQt4        ## 別記エラー２
● pip install --upgrade pip
● pip install PyQt4        ## 別記エラー３

以上３回行いましたが同じ症状でした

何かしらのヒントやアドバイスがありましたらお願いいたします。

※ Windows版 anaconda3 では正しくグラフが表示されます。

【追記、その後行った事】
[stackoverflow.com にて同じ症状に対するページがありました。](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1068)
pyqt5 が原因なのか・・・? 
最下段の対応策を行いました。

```
conda install -y pyqt=4.11
```

これで PyQt4 に対するエラーはなくなりましたが

新たに libSM.so.6 エラーが発生しました。
[これも stackoverflow.com にて同じ症状](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1051)に対するページがあったので対応策を実行しました。

```
apt-get install libsm6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1
```

これで前記のエラーはなくなりましたが

また RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable が出てきました。orz

Display表示ができない状態なので超目先の対応としてグラフを画像として保存することにしました。 
※ date_demo.py 修正コード 参照

しかし、画像が保存されません。 (涙) orz ※ Windows版では同じコードで画像保存されます。

今ここまで ・・・

(別記エラー１)

```
$ python date_demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "date_demo.py", line 16, in <module>
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/mnt/c/Users/Admin/.BashHome/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 114, in <module>
_backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
File "/mnt/c/Users/Admin/.BashHome/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
File "/mnt/c/Users/Admin/.BashHome/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
  from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
File "/mnt/c/Users/Admin/.BashHome/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 31, in <module>
  from .qt_compat import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, _getSaveFileName, __version__
File "/mnt/c/Users/Admin/.BashHome/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 137, in <module>
  from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

(別記エラー２)

```
$ pip install PyQt4
Collecting PyQt4
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt4
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

（別記エラー３）

```
$ pip install PyQt4 
Collecting PyQt4
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt4
```

date_demo.py 修正コード

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl            ## 加筆
mpl.use('Agg')                      ## 加筆
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

years = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

datafile = cbook.get_sample_data('goog.npy')
try:
    r = np.load(datafile, encoding='bytes').view(np.recarray)
except TypeError:
    r = np.load(datafile).view(np.recarray)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(r.date, r.adj_close)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)

datemin = datetime.date(r.date.min().year, 1, 1)
datemax = datetime.date(r.date.max().year + 1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)

def price(x):
    return '$%1.2f' % x
ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.format_ydata = price
ax.grid(True)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

fig.savefig('date_demo.py.png')    ## 加筆

# plt.show()    ## コメントアウト
```

【環境】
WIndows 10
bash on windows
anaconda3-4.2.0

```
$ conda info
Current conda install:

               platform : linux-64
          conda version : 4.2.13
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.2.13
    conda-build version : 2.0.2
         python version : 3.5.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.11.1
       root environment : /mnt/c/Users/Admin/.BashHome/anaconda3  (writable)
    default environment : /mnt/c/Users/Admin/.BashHome/anaconda3
       envs directories : /mnt/c/Users/Admin/.BashHome/anaconda3/envs
          package cache : /mnt/c/Users/Admin/.BashHome/anaconda3/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
            config file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: 自己解決により質問を閉じたいのですが、操作方法がわかりまん。

Comment: まず、解決した内容を「回答」として投稿します。その後、48時間以上まち、その回答を承認します。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: (質問投稿後から2日たっているので待つ必要はない)

Answer (score 3):

2016/11/26 時点で質問に下記の報告がありました。

---

自己解決したので同じ症状の方のために書き残しておきたいと思います。

● anaconda3 インストール
● conda install nomkl
● sudo apt-get install x11-apps
● Windows 10 にて [xming](https://osdn.jp/projects/sfnet_xming/) をインストールして Xming.exe 起動

テストコード

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

PyQt4 エラーは解決していませんが、 matplotlib でグラフの画像保存と表示ができるようになりました。